# Elastic Beanstalk Error (Python Environment)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy an application that had been working in a Single Instance environment after rebuilding that environment to find that the deploy fails. Regardless of what I do (I've tried to deploy versions I've known to be able to deploy in the past), I keep seeing a variant of this message in /var/log/eb-activity.log, and I'm not quite sure what to make of it, or how to get more information, since I'm not sure what environment AWS uses to spool up their commands:

INFO  [3031]  - [Application deployment app-*/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...

I don't believe any of my ebextensions are breaking the system as I've tried to deploy versions of my application where there have only been essential packages being installed, and these too, fail. In summation, I was wondering if there were logs that I might be able to look into to diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that yum commands in ebextensions script really mess things up. Use the rpm command on the Amazon Linux environment.